# Python: Loop through regex patterns to create a “expression list” within a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a more efficient way to apply a set of regular expressions to a column of a dataframe to produce a “regex list” as the row output. Currently what I have works but becomes super slow on large datasets.

df has one column, let’s call it text

```
# Create a column for each regex with a binary match
expressions = [regex1, …, regexN]
for exp in expressions:
   df[exp] = df[text].str.contains(exp)

# Create a list of regular expressions from the output of each new columns 
df[‘exp_list’] = df[expressions].apply(lambda x: x.index[x==True].tolist(), axis=1)
```

Then I drop the expressions columns. This is the best I could come up with but it’s still way too slow. I’ve tried nested list comprehension, tried using the re package, but it’s all much slower.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you got example/input someone can work with? And some idea of what scale you're running this and how many columns you expect as output?

Comment: (what about submatches... eg... if something matches `abc` should it also be considered to match `ab` or `a` or `b` or just `c` etc...)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.